# Is there a way to create logical diagrams in plantuml?

Tags: plantuml

Does plantuml have an ability to create logical diagrams visualization based on elements "AND" "OR"?

For example, if I had expression like:

```
A x B + B x C + A x C = Output
```

it would create visualization like this:

[image]

Quick view via plantuml help and google search result doesn't give such  option. Maybe there exist another sites allowing to convert text expressions into logical diagrams?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm looking for the same kind of tool. I have found those two to be helpful:

- https://digitaljs.tilk.eu/
- https://rtsys.informatik.uni-kiel.de/elklive/elkgraph.html

Comment: Thank you. Keep us informed if you find another gem